# GKSession alloc / release / alloc = leaks and crashes

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, gamekit, gksession

I've got an app that throws out the GKSession and makes a new one under various conditions (connection timeout, session fails, etc.). I'm getting memory leaks, though, and it sometimes crashes after a few loops through the reconnect.

Here's my code:

```
- (void) netConnect:(id) sender {
     NSLog(@"allocating GKSession");

     currentSession = [[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:nil displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];
     currentSession.delegate = self;
     currentSession.available = YES;
     currentSession.disconnectTimeout = 0;
     [currentSession setDataReceiveHandler: self withContext:nil]; 
        }

- (void) netDisconnect:(id) sender {
     NSLog(@"DISCONNECTING BY REQUEST");

     [currentSession disconnectFromAllPeers];
     [currentSession setAvailable:NO];
     [currentSession setDelegate:nil];
     [currentSession setDataReceiveHandler:nil withContext:nil];
     [currentSession release];
     currentSession = nil;
    }
```

There's a timer that waits for a successful connection; if it doesn't get one, netDisconnect is called, followed by netConnect again after a 5-second NSTimer delay.

I'm getting leaked GKList, GKTable, and GKAutoPeerIDTable objects, and crashes like this (always occurs after the alloc) :

```
  Date/Time:       2010-09-05 09:35:59.426 -0700
  OS Version:      iPhone OS 4.0.2 (8A400)
  Report Version:  104

  Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGBUS)
  Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x0000000a
  Crashed Thread:  0

  Thread 0 Crashed:
  0   libobjc.A.dylib                0x0000286c objc_msgSend + 16
  1   CoreFoundation                 0x000756ea __CFCopyFormattingDescription + 174
  2   CoreFoundation                 0x00081c8e __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 8666
  3   CoreFoundation                 0x000146ac _CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArgumentsAux + 64
  4   CoreFoundation                 0x00014660 CFStringCreateWithFormatAndArguments + 16
  5   CoreFoundation                 0x0001463c CFStringCreateWithFormat + 16
  6   SystemConfiguration            0x00003272 SCDynamicStoreCreateWithOptions + 62
  7   SystemConfiguration            0x000033d0 SCDynamicStoreCreate + 12
  8   GameKitServices                0x000020ce gckRegisterForNetworkChanges + 154
  9   GameKitServices                0x000035c0 GCKSessionCreate + 788
  10  GameKitServices                0x00035e7a -[GKSessionInternal initWithSessionID:displayName:session:sessionMode:] + 274
  11  GameKit                        0x0000fda8 -[GKSession initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:] + 76
```

Here's another one:

```
Sun Sep  5 10:28:52 thinner someapp[424] <Warning>: allocating GKSession
Sun Sep  5 10:28:52 thinner someapp[424] <Error>: -[__NSCFData UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a710
Sun Sep  5 10:28:52 thinner someapp[424] <Error>: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFData UTF8String]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x10a710'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x31a9ffd3 __exceptionPreprocess + 114
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x3428a8a5 objc_exception_throw + 24
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x31aa3a77 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 102
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x31aa2f15 ___forwarding___ + 508
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x31a35680 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 48
    5   GameKitServices                     0x327aff13 -[GKSessionInternal initWithSessionID:displayName:session:sessionMode:] + 426
    6   GameKit                             0x31c15daf -[GKSession initWithSessionID:displayName:sessionMode:] + 82
    7   someapp                        0x0000584b -[MainViewController netConnect:] + 126
```

Questions:
• Is this the right way to release and re-allocate GKSessions?
• Should I not be tearing down and re-allocating GKSessions between connections to begin with?

Comment: I'm leaning towards GameKit being buggy, but not releasing the session is the better way to go anyway when the intent is to keep trying to connect or reconnect.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you but I've been fiddling with GKSession for two days now and yes, it seems to crash often and frequently on dealloc... It seems really bad...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue.  The workaround is to not pass in nil for the sessionID: 
[[GKSession alloc] initWithSessionID:@"com.put.something.here" displayName:nil sessionMode:GKSessionModePeer];